# Chrome Extension Open Local Word Document

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, google-chrome-extension

My users have given my extension access to local files.  I can point to PDF at a known local location and direct chrome to open new tab at that "URL" such that the PDF is opened in chrome's PDF viewer.

However, I want to open word documents and I want to give users direct access from within my extensions GUI to open those local PDFs with their native browser.

When a person is using chrome normally and downloads either of these file types, they can click the file in their browser tab and direct chrome to open the file, in either the native PDF viewer or word.

Is there any way at all to get a similar result, i.e. get my extension to open the files it has access to in the program associated as he default program to use with that file type?

Comment: You'll have to create an additional utility that runs separately in OS, communicates with your extension via nativeMessaging API, and launches documents.

Comment: I obviously know that is possible.  What I want to know is whether there is any solution inside chrome.

Comment: There is no API to open files in external programs, so writing an external program yourself that will communicate with the extensions via nativeMessaging is the only solution.

Comment: That there isn't an API does not imply it is not possible.

Comment: Okay, 3rd attempt. Chrome does not allow extensions to open arbitrary external programs. The only allowed method is using nativeMessaging API to register the native messaging host application.

Comment: What about when a user downloads a file and clicks the file from within chrome?  In that instance chrome opens the file in the default application assigned by the OS.

Comment: To state the obvious, a downloaded file is a special case which doesn't help here.

Comment: Okay but my point is that your matter of fact "no" answer fails to consider special cases.  Maybe there is a special case hacky solution.  If it were easy I would have just known how to do it.  But that doesn't mean it's impossible.

Comment: I've simply omitted the case of downloads API because it's unusable for the task. There are no solutions other than nativeMessaging API, hacky or not. If there were it would be a security bug fixed immediately.

Comment: The security concern is still significant with pdfs.  This is a scenario where I already have access to viewing arbitrarily located locally saved PDFs.